# Is password defense on-topic?

Tags: discussion

So there are those platforms where, if you forget your password, you can get sent a prerecorded hint.

Would it be off-topic to provide this hint in a question, as a means to ensure it can't be cracked except by myself?

Comment: You can always put comments in the body of  your post, they won't show up in the post and you're allowed to make those as cryptic as you wish.

Comment: Let me give an oversimplified example: My email password is "kangaroo84". I set the password reminder hint to "australia orwell". Then I create a new post on puzzling which has the body "australia orwell", and if noone finds it, I feel safe about my password hint. I am asking if it is OK to do that.

Comment: I feel like sharing sensitive info like this (in the present case, hints about your password) isn't a good fit for Puzzling, if you wish to have a team of password crackers trying to decode your pass from hint(s), I'm not sure this is the right place to do so, you could disguise it as a puzzle though, that way nobody will really know if it's your password. Also [obligatory XKCD post](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: @Auribouros Love the XKCD. As a matter of fact, I did follow randall's advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### I would advise against this for several reasons

1. From a puzzle-solver's point of view, this does not really make for a very interesting puzzle experience. It is effectively 'guess what I'm thinking' via word association.
2. As a result of this, you will likely receive answer posts containing many multiples of guesses, and many multiples of answer posts at that. This would probably result in your post being closed for '**may invite speculative answers**'. After all, if there is no clear logical deduction path, speculation is all this ever will be.
3. If, after a few days, you ultimately decide 'Ha, nobody cracked it! I shall use this as my password hint!' who's to say it wouldn't be cracked after one day more, or eventually? You would have effectively provided a would-be password hacker with additional information for free, even if you consider it very unlikely they would stumble upon this somehow. But the fact is: people do. **It isn't worth the risk.**